# GCP Set up Cloud Build Trigger for Bitbucket via the API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-deployment-manager

Is it possible to set up a Cloud Build Trigger for Bitbucket via the API? If so, how do you do it? My end goal is to automate the infrastructure deployment through Deployment Manager so some guidance on that would be appreciated as well.

I see that the API supports GitHub but nothing is mentioned about Bitbucket:
https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers

In terms of Deployment Manager, there are these samples but the first doesn't help with triggers and the second doesn't use Bitbucket.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/cloudbuild
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/community/cloud-foundation/templates/cloudbuild